# Transparent App Background on S8 After Android 8.0 Update

Tags: android, samsung-mobile, samsung-galaxy

We have an app that has an optional transparent background that can be toggled on and off by the user.  We're getting reports from customers, and confirmed ourselves, that the latest Samsung S8 update that included Android 8.0 broke this feature.  Now instead of a transparent background we're seeing a black background.  Is anyone else seeing this?  Are there any workarounds?

We're seeing the background to transparent via a custom theme in styles.xml:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="android:Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar">
    <item name="android:listViewStyle">@style/MyListView</item>
    <item name="android:listViewWhiteStyle">@style/MyListViewWhite</item>
    <item name="android:editTextStyle">@style/MyEditTextStyle</item>
    <item name="android:spinnerStyle">@style/MySpinnerStyle</item>
    <item name="android:spinnerItemStyle">@style/MySpinnerItem</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

same thing for me. It seems it has something to do with Samsung's game launcher app.
It tries to "optimize" games by removing transparencies.
We've had some luck with these settings:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <style name="Theme.Transparent" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <!--item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item-->
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```